# Python generator cannot be converted to list

Tags: python, list, generator

in Python I need to get the permutation of a list of integers. And I used a generator function and it seemed to have the proper result. Then I tried to transform the iterator to a list. However, the list returns the permutations without order. I wonder if there is any way to correct it. Thanks.

```
def permu(arr, start = 0):
    if start == len(arr):
        yield arr
    for i in range(start, len(arr)):
        arr[start], arr[i] = arr[i], arr[start]
        for x in permu(arr, start + 1):
            yield x
        arr[start], arr[i] = arr[i], arr[start]

def wrapper(arr):
    return list(permu(arr))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for p in permu([1, 2 ,3]):
        print p

    print wrapper([1, 2, 3])
```

The result is like --

```
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 3, 2]
[2, 1, 3]
[2, 3, 1]
[3, 2, 1]
[3, 1, 2]

[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Comment: would `combinations()` help? https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations

Comment: @shavenwarthog you surely mean `permutations`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are sharing **one** list object, and only are altering the contents. `wrapper()` returns a list with 6 references to that *one* list:

```
>>> res = wrapper([1, 2, 3])
>>> res[0] is res[1]
True
>>> res[0] is res[2]
True
>>> res[0][0] = 42
>>> res
[[42, 2, 3], [42, 2, 3], [42, 2, 3], [42, 2, 3], [42, 2, 3], [42, 2, 3]]
```

You could yield copies instead:

```
def permu(arr, start = 0):
    if start == len(arr):
        yield arr[:]
    for i in range(start, len(arr)):
        arr[start], arr[i] = arr[i], arr[start]
        for x in permu(arr, start + 1):
            yield x
        arr[start], arr[i] = arr[i], arr[start]
```

or you could use [`itertools.permutations()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations):

```
>>> from itertools import permutations
>>> print list(permutations([1, 2, 3]))
[(1, 2, 3), (1, 3, 2), (2, 1, 3), (2, 3, 1), (3, 1, 2), (3, 2, 1)]
```